# android: ClassCastException when trying to cast Fragments

Tags: java, android, oop, android-fragments, casting

I'm developing an app where users can create and edit their own quizzes. I have two fragments, `EditQuizFragment` and `AddQuizFragment`, one of which extends the other:

```
public class EditQuizFragment extends Fragment
public class AddQuizFragment extends EditQuizFragment
```

I want to cast `AddQuizFragment` (the subclass) onto an `EditQuizFragment`.

When I try to run the following, I get a `ClassCastException`:

```
EditQuizFragment editQuizFragment = new EditQuizFragment();
AddQuizFragment addQuizFragment = (AddQuizFragment) editQuizFragment;
```

Here's the error message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.quizmaker.fragments.EditQuizFragment cannot be cast to com.quizmaker.fragments.AddQuizFragment
```

I've tried moving the error-causing code to other classes, files, etc, but still get the same `ClassCastException`. What's the reason for this? I thought the cast would work.

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated!

---

**EDIT:** Found a workaround. So the reason I was trying to cast was because I was using the [newInstance pattern for fragments](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/using-newinstance-to-instantiate.html). In `AddQuizFragment.java` I was trying to do something like this:

```
public static AddQuizFragment newInstance() {
    return (AddQuizFragment) EditQuizFragment.newInstance( /* arguments here */ );
}
```

This is what was causing the `ClassCastException`.

All `newInstance` does is set the arguments bundle for the fragment, abstracting that away from classes using the fragment. So instead of the above, I did the below:

```
public static AddQuizFragment newInstance() {
    EditQuizFragment editQuizFragment = EditQuizFragment.newInstance(/* arguments here */);
    AddQuizFragment addQuizFragment = new AddQuizFragment();
    addQuizFragment.setArguments(editQuizFragment.getArguments());
    return addQuizFragment;
}
```

Comment: In the same sense that all squares are rectangles but not all rectangles are squares, all `AddQuizFragment`s are `EditQuizFragments`, but not the other way around.  You have `new EditQuizFragment()` which does not create an `AddQuizFragment`.

Comment: @TavianBarnes Please see my reply to Kiskae's answer

Answer (score 2):

`AddQuizFragment` is an `EditQuizFragment`, but `EditQuizFragment` is not an `AddQuizFragment`.

You simply cannot do this unless `editQuizFragment` is an object that implements `AddQuizFragment`